# Defining additional character subset names in fontconfig.properties in jre

Tags: java, unicode, fonts

Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) about font configuration file states:

> CharacterSubsetName - a name for a subset of the Unicode character set
> which certain component fonts can render. For Windows, the following
> names are predefined: alphabetic, arabic, chinese-ms936,
> .....................

(the list goes on)

> "A font configuration file may define additional names to identify
> additional character subsets."

What is the format and where in the fontconfig file should I define additional names for additional character subsets?